# How to get data from database in a loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
<script>  <?php  if($pid>0) { ?>
  var counter=<?php echo $rnum ?>; <?php } else { ?>
 var counter = 1;   <?php  } ?>
 var limit = 25;
 //function addInput()--------      
    function addInput()
      {
      var dt=counter+1;  dpid="#datepicker1".concat(dt); dp="datepicker1".concat(dt); djid="#datepicker2".concat(dt); dj="datepicker2".concat(dt);

      if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
        }
        else {
            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<div class='row no-margin' id='row"+dt+"'><div class='col-md-6 input box'><input name='tkid[]' type='hidden' value='0' id='itemid"+dt+"'><select name='item[]' ><option value='' disabled selected required>Deliverables</option><option value='website'>Website</option><option value='app'>Web Application</option><option value='domain'>Domain Registration</option><option value='hosting'>Hosting</option><option value='content'>Content Writing</option><option value='logo'>Logo Creation</option><option value='analytics'>Google Analytics</option></select></div><div class='col-md-6 input box'><select name='assignedto[]'><option value='' disabled selected required>Assigned To</option><option value='value1'> Value1</option><option value='value2'>Value2</option></select></div><div class='col-md-6 input box' id='dynamicInput1'><input type='text' id='".concat(dp).concat("' name='actualtime[]' placeholder='Actual Time Required' value='' required></div><div class='col-md-5 input box' id='dynamicInput1'><input type='text' id='").concat(dj).concat("' name='ddate[]' placeholder='Delivery Date' value='' required></div><div class='col-md-1 input box'><i class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true' onclick='deleteinput("+dt+")'></i></div></div>");
          dp=document.getElementById('dynamicInput').appendChild(newdiv);
          dg=document.getElementById("dynamicInput").style.display="inline-block";
          counter++;
          document.getElementById("count").value=counter;
          $(dpid).datepicker({minDate: new Date(),dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
          $(djid).datepicker({minDate: new Date(),dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});

      }
         //data: {'aid':aid},
         $.ajax({
          url: 'project.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: 'dcount'+counter,
          success: function(output) 
          {   //$(".container").html(output)
              //alert(dt);
              //alert('success, server says '+output);
          }, error: function()
          {
              alert('something went wrong, rating failed');
          }

        });
      };

</script>
```

How can i get values from database into select option. Not from the above code. This is a dynamically adding textfield. And I want the values added to the database in the dynamic field.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not that clear to me

if you are asking for a technique to add select menu with the dynamic input, better use ajax

like

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: 'list.php',
data: {
list1 :val
},
success: function (response) {
document.getElementById("itemlist").innerHTML=response; 
}
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['list1']))
{   
$state = $_POST['list1'];
$find=mysqli_query($con,"select city from places where state='$state'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($find))
{
echo "<option>".$row['item']."</option>";
 }
exit;
}  
?>
```